# How do I get author information for an SVN revision number?

Tags: svn, git

What is the `svn` equivalent of this command, basically?

```
 git show  -s  --pretty="format:%an"    85c3e0
```

I have a revision number and I need the author for that checkin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only think of something like this:

```
svn info [-rXXX] | grep "Author" | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: you can skip the grep: `svn info [-rXXX] | awk '/Author/{print $4}'`

Comment: Yup. No need for `grep` here, as [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604873/how-do-i-get-author-information-for-an-svn-revision-number/6607019#6607019) demonstrates.

Answer (score 4):

Use `svn info` command on your working copy.

Basic `svn info` will give you the following Information (Sample):

```
Path: .
URL: http://svn.myorg.net/Project/branches/Release1/Src
Repository Root: http://svn.myorg.net/Project/
Repository UUID: bbd6f5fb-5b8a-4d5b-891f-9a174ed27ad1
Revision: 7667
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: author
Last Changed Rev: 7656
Last Changed Date: 2011-06-28 19:08:07 +0530 (Tue, 28 Jun 2011)
```

The key values in this information are: **Revision**, **Last Changed Author**, and **Last Changed Revision**

For a particular revision, run: `svn info -r [rev_no]`

You can filter out the results.

Answer (score 2):

`svn info` + `awk`:

```
 svn info -r327 | awk -F':' '/Last Changed Author/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

From a client machine, using GUI like tortoise SVN is easier than using commandline.

However, if you are a SVN admin and are looking to get the info from the SVN server itself(example as an SVN admin], below command can be used :

svnlook author -r[revision number] [repository path where the particular svn repository resides physically on server]

Answer (score 0):

svn info with --show-item is the simplest way:

```
svn info --show-item last-changed-author [-rXXX]
```